# How to download fsl

Tags: python, macos, heredoc, xquartz, fslab

I have been trying to install the fsl in my macOS. However, I haven't found any particular script for the installation yet. I have installed XQuartz and have conda in the Mac. I would really appreciate it the help.
Thanks.

I tried several scripts from the installation site. For example:
VERSION="1.6"
POSIXLY_CORRECT=1

cecho () {
string=$@
my_os=`os`
if [ "X${my_os}" = "XLinux" ]; then
echo -e "$string "
elif [ "X${my_os}" = "XSunOS"  ]; then
echo "$string"
elif [ `darwin_release` -lt 9 ]; then
echo -e "$string"
else
echo "$string"
fi
}

skipped () {
message=$@

```
cecho "\033[34;1m[Skipped]\033[0m $message"
```

}

ok () {
message=$@

```
cecho "\033[32;1m[OK]\033[0m $message"
```

}

failed () {
message=$@

```
cecho "\033[31;1m[Failed]\033[0m $message"
```

}

warning () {
message=$@

```
cecho "\033[31m[Warning]\033[0m $message"
```

}

Usage () {
cat <<USAGE

fsl_installer.sh [-f  [-d ] [-x] [-e] [-p] [-h] [-C]]

I am new to this. I would really appreciate the help and consideration.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Hello I would like to install fsl in my macOS. My question was if there's any particular script that may help me with the installation?